# Why $a'(X'X)^{-1}a\leq \lambda_{\max}[(X'X)^{-1}]$ with $a'a=1$ and $\lambda_{\max}[\cdot]$ gives the largest eigenvalue of a matrix?

Tags: inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, symmetric-matrices

In a lecture note I read about the following line in a proof: $a'(X'X)^{-1}a\leq \lambda_{\max}[(X'X)^{-1}]=[\lambda_{\min}(X'X)]^{-1}$, where $a'a=1$, $\lambda_{\max}[(X'X)^{-1}]$ gives the largest eigenvalue of matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$ and $\lambda_{\min}(X'X)$ gives the minimum eigenvalue of matrix $X'X$. I'm wondering why $a'(X'X)^{-1}a\leq \lambda_{\max}[(X'X)^{-1}]$ and why $\lambda_{\max}[(X'X)^{-1}]=[\lambda_{\min}(X'X)]^{-1}$. Both seems quite unintuitive to me, and it would be great if you could provide the theorems or results used here. Thanks!

Comment: The above addresses the inequality part. Also note that eigenvalues of the inverse of a positive definite matrix are the inverses of the eigenvalues of the matrix since $$Ax =\lambda x\iff \lambda^{-1}x=A^{-1}x.$$ So the equality you seek follows immediately.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks a lot! This is very helpful. Just a quick question, the second inequality of your reference said $x'Px\leq \lambda_{\max}||x||^2$ while I want $x'Px\leq \lambda_{\max}(P)$. How to fill up this gap?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thank you very much! This is very helpful! Could you also give a bit guidance on how the reference in V.S.e.H.'s answer completely addresses the inequality part?

Comment: @ExcitedSnail In your problem, $x=a$ and $\|x\|^2=\|a\|^2=a'a=1,$ and $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ in their notation corresponds with $\lambda_\text{max}(P)$ in your notation